# Blender can't see through glass because reflections are too hard

Tags: shaders, glass, reflection

I have this mesh
[image]

When I add glass on top of it I can't see through it when I'm at an angle.
[image]

The glass material is an extremely basic one. [image]

How can I make it that the glass acts more naturally?(more see through less reflection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by giving the glass thickness with the solidify modifier.

Comment: also maybe mix the node with a Transparent node?